# Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

Tags: java

I have a pretty simple method here:

```
    private String claimAsString(
        JWTClaimsSet claims,
        String claimName,
        String fallbackClaimName)
    {
        Object claim = claims.getClaim(claimName);
        if (claim != null)
        {
            return (String) claim;
        }

        Object fallbackClaim = claims.getClaim(fallbackClaimName);
        if (fallbackClaim != null)
        {
            return (String) fallbackClaim;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Basically to get a claim from a JWT claimset, and if it doesn't exist, get the fallback value. But it looks like the 2 blocks of the code are too similar... just wondering if there is a better way to re-write this to be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Did you try with Java 8 `Optional`?

Comment: I agree, an `Optional.of()` and a `map` invocation can simplify the whole thing.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo `Optional.ofNullable()` won't throw an NPE when its argument is null so I tend to favor it. You're right about the `Map`, especially its `compute()` method that perfectly fits the problem.

Comment: @Matthieu I would be interested to see an answer based on this idea.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this if you're a fan of one-liners:

```
Object claim = claims.getStringClaim(claimName);
return (String) (claim == null ? claims.getStringClaim(fallbackClaimName) : claim);
```

However you might want to consider changing your `claimAsString` method to have an `Optional` return type. Then you could do:

```
Optional<String> claimAsString(JWTClaimsSet claims, String claimName, String fallbackClaimName) {
    
    return Optional.ofNullable((String) claims.get(claimName))
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable((String) claims.get(fallbackClaimName)));
}
```

Comment: If first condition will be true and second method will return null, in this case it will throw exception.

Comment: Will it? Why is that?

Comment: Because you are casting it to String.

Comment: Do you mean casting? If so then you don't get an exception when casting `null` to a any type?

Comment: Seems ok to me, nothing wrong with `(String) null`.

Comment: I don't see any issues @VivekJain https://ideone.com/3W41X9

Comment: Hey, my apology, it would work fine, please edit and save again this answer so I can cancel my down vote for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, you could do the whole thing in one line (or two if you prefer):

```
return (String) Optional.ofNullable(claims.getClaim(claimName))
    .orElseGet(() -> claims.getClaim(fallbackClaimName));
```

If you're using an older compiler, as a general technique you can iterate through the two search strings:

```
private String claimAsString(
    JWTClaimsSet claims,
    String claimName,
    String fallbackClaimName)
{
    for (String searchedClaim : new String[] {claimName, fallbackClaimName}) {
        Object claim = claims.getClaim(searchedClaim);
        if (claim != null) {
            return (String) claim;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I found the correct docs for the class you are using but you could try it like this. `getClaim` or `getStringClaim` return null if no value is found, so you do not need the null check there.

```
private String claimAsString(
    JWTClaimsSet claims,
    String claimName,
    String fallbackClaimName)
{
    String claim = claims.getStringClaim(claimName);
    if (claim != null){
        return claim;
    }
    return claims.getStringClaim(fallbackClaimName);
}
```